# How to convert String into String Array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a string with city names separated with commas like this: {Tokyo, New York, Amsterdam}

How do you convert this to a String[] array like {"Tokyo", "New York", "Amsterdam"}

Comment: @Meiko That one shows how to split one word into individual letters. This question asks how to split the string by the commas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Split on ",".

```
String st = "Tokyo, New York, Amsterdam"
String[] arr = st.split(",");
```

If `st` has '{' and '}'. You might want to do something along the lines of...

```
st = st.replace("{","").replace("}","");
```

to get rid of the '{' and '}'.

Comment: @DougStevenson Haha Let me update it :)